# Packages not found from Nuget command line

Tags: nexus

I am trying to list the package using below command but getting

> no package found

output, even though I have packages in the `Nexus` repository.

```
nuget list "path of my repo"
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 2):

Running the scheduled task "rebuild nuget feed" against the repository path solved this issue.

Comment: P.S : only a nexus admin can run the scheduled task.